# I do not find web.config in cgi-bin folder?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I do configuration in iis in cognos 10. But I dont find web config file in cgi-bin folder.
How can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Microsoft KB article is good at helping identify the various locations the IIS config files might exist at:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28WS.10%29.aspx

In my experience the web.config is placed at the location that your Application (not Virtual Directory) is configured, though not always.

Comment: Web.config would exist in your base VD, unless there are specific settings for cgi-bin. In IIS every folder, can have its own web.config, but Cognos usually needs just one (if any).